# Changing Innodb_buffer_pool_instances

Tags: mysql

Using mysql 5.6

innodb size is 512M

```
default is Innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
```

Trying to add in my.cnf

```
Innodb_buffer_pool_instances=1
```

getting error

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown variable 'Innodb_buffer_pool_instances=1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `innodb_buffer_pool_instances`, with a lowercase `i`.

Comment: Lol... too much computer time. thank you.